# Send object as hex through web service ¿Its a good programing practice?

Tags: web-services, object, hex, byte

I was wondering how good is to get an object bytes and convert them to HEX in order to send it through a web service, and then in the client side, they will convert the HEX to the same object. I already try this and it works, but I don't know if it is a good practice. Thank you.

Comment: pro: you'll stay in the range of permitted characters for all transmission protocols involved. con: depending on the precise nature of the object you are transmitting, reconstruction may not be possible at the destination (construed example: think of references to memory locations as part ofyour object).

Comment: on a second thought, most programming environments feature a serialization abstraction which provides the service to convert to and from a representation amenable to transmissions over common protocols.  this should be a suitable starting point. if required, you may apply a generic encoding like base64 on top to restrict the transmitted data to a limited range of octets used. any inconvenient size blow-up might be countered by applying compression prior to octet-range reduction.